# Rspec throwing crazy error when I add an "order" parameter to will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a **User** and a **Post** model. And I'm showing the user's posts in the user show view:

**users_controller.rb:**

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    default_order = "created_at DESC"
    params[:order_by] ||= default_order 
    @posts = @user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],
                                  per_page: 10,
                                  order: params[:order_by]) if signed_in?
    @posts = @user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

**users/show.html.erb:**

```
<% if @user.posts.any? %>
  <h3>Posts (<%= @user.posts.count %>)</h3>

  <ul class="posts unstyled">
    <%= render @posts %>
  </ul>
  <%= will_paginate @posts %>
<% end %>
```

The posts display fine in the live site. But when I run this spec:

**user_pages_spec.rb:**

```
  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let!(:p1) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: user, title: "Fo",
                                   content: "Foo") }
    let!(:p2) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: user, title: "Ba",
                                   content: "Bar") }

    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

    describe "posts" do
      it { should have_content(p1.title) }
      it { should have_content(p1.content) }
      it { should have_content(p2.title) }
      it { should have_content(p2.content) }
      it { should have_content(user.posts.count) }
    end
  end
```

I get this crazy error:

```
 6) User pages profile page posts 
      Failure/Error: it { should have_content(p1.title) }
        expected there to be content "Fo" in "Action Controller: Exception caught 
          body { background-color: #fff; color: #333; }
          body, p, ol, ul, td {
            font-family: helvetica, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
            font-size:   13px;      
            line-height: 18px;
          }
          pre {
            background-color: #eee;     
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 11px;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
          }    
          a { color: #000; }
          a:visited { color: #666; }   
          a:hover { color: #fff; background-color:#000; } 

          ArgumentError in
            Users#show



          Showing /home/alex/rails/inkleak/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #20 raised:
          'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.

           Extracted source (around line #20):
           17: <h3>Posts (<%= @user.posts.count %>)
```

and goes and goes and goes...like thousand lines.

It's strange because the test works just fine if I comment these line:

```
 #default_order = "created_at DESC"
    #params[:order_by] ||= default_order 

    #order: params[:order_by])
```

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

Here are my factories:

**factories.rb:**

```
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}   
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end

  factory :post do
    title "lorem"
    content "lorem ipsum"
    #tagging
    category
    user
    after(:build) do |post|
      post.tags << FactoryGirl.build(:tag)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you show line #20 of that error you posted? That's where it says the error is.

Comment: @LeoCorrea This is line 20 in user show view: `<%= render @posts %>` is that what you meant?

Comment: do you have a factory defined for :tag? It might be complaining about that. On the `post.tags << FactoryGirl.build(:tag)

Comment: @Leo Correa Yes, in fact, all the tests pass, except this one. And the test passes if I remove `order` from `will_paginate` in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `order` incorrectly with will_paginate.

This is how you'd do it:

```
@user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).order(params[:order_by])
```

[Source](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki)